# How does microservice architecture handle situations when immediate response is required?

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architecture, microservices

What is the best practice of a multi-step processing in a micro-service system  which is using publish/subscribe architecture as internal source of communication and also requires immediate response?
Is that even possible?

Example would be a tourist agency which is exposing an API to their partners.
API allows to book an accommodation via API (including payment).

There are several problems with this.

1. Credit card could be protected by 3D secure, which requires additional input from user
2. Payment is processed on a different micro-service
3. Inventory and Booking are separate micro-services

This story works well if you are designing an api for your application, where you can separate payment process from booking process and pool for events to display some sort of loading screen in process.

What if that same api is exposed to the outside world/partners and it requires immediate response?

Example would be, a partner submits payment data and necessary booking information in the same request, and requires response immediately.

Even separating payment to one request, and then adding another request towards booking micro-service with payment ID presents a problem, cause booking micro-service requires communication with inventory micro-service to finish process.

Possible solution would be a direct HTTP communication between microservices, but that would be a tight coupling.

Are micro-services wrong set of tools to handle situations like this?

Comment: Don't tourist agencies usually just rely on reservation blockers? At least you can have them block certain tickets for up to X days with the current pricing conditions. Sounds like a simple solution to all of your problems.

Comment: @Frank if a booking micro-service is a point of entry, it needs to signal inventory micro-service to reserve certain accommodation for certain period. It also needs to verify if the accommodation is available in requested period.

Comment: @MainMa in the question you linked OP said that he has a several options to go, and my question is more based on "is this achievable with my approach, or I am using wrong tools"

Comment: @Robert: as I see it, your question is about how to handle requests which may take time to answer because they rely on the asynchronous aspect of ESB (or should you redesign your current message queue service approach by something else). In my understanding, the question I linked is indeed a duplicate, since it shows how this can be done. Either your block the client until you receive the response through MQS, or you reply with `HTTP 202 Accepted` and either let the client figure out when the process finishes, or use WebSockets to notify the client.